# Why does NuGet install two copies of JavaScript packages?

Tags: javascript, nuget, visual-studio-2013

When I install JavaScript packages in Visual Studio using NuGet, targeting Project1, I find the scripts are installed into the Solution1/Project1/Scripts folder of the target Project, and **also** into the Solution1/packages folder.

What is the point of this additional copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the packages folder as a cache. If you had multiple projects in the solution, they would copy their local copies out of the packages folder into their individual directories. The idea is that you only have to download the actual nuget package once and in the event that a project gets messed up, it just refreshes its copy from the cache.

The packages folder also contains much more than just the javascript files. It has instructions for modifying the config files, the nuget package definition, and a few other tidbits that visual studio uses to keep track of them.

Answer (score 1):

For content packages like jQuery, you would still have multiple copies of the .js file on your system, just like the DLLs that get copied into your bin folder.  You just wouldn't have the *package* folder copied with every solution.

For packages that have binaries that support lots of frameworks, you presently have the binaries for every framework supported sitting in each solution's packages folder, regardless of which frameworks the solution is using.  With a global package installation, you'd have 1 global package install, and then each project would copy into its bin the assemblies that apply to it.